# "Is this estimator fitted" error while trying to predict on pre trained Model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle, pipeline, streamlit

I have trained a model using the following code:

```
# Train model
pipeline = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(),  GaussianNB())
model = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)
classification_metrics(pipeline, conf_matrix)

# save model
pickle.dump(model, open("cropRecommendation.pkl", "wb"))
```

And I am trying to load and predict on a single sample using the code:

```
pickle_in4 = open("cropRecommendation.pkl","rb")
model4=pickle.load(pickle_in4)
feature_list = [N, P, K, temp, humidity, ph, rainfall]
        single_pred = np.array(feature_list).reshape(1,-1)
        
        if st.button('Predict'):

            prediction = model4.predict(single_pred)
            
            st.success(f"{prediction.item().title()} are recommended by the A.I for your farm.")
```

But the streamlit page returns the error :

```
RuntimeError: The reset parameter is False but there is no n_features_in_ attribute. Is this estimator fitted?
Traceback:
File "c:\users\misra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 337, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\misra\GithubProjects\AgriAI\web_app.py", line 851, in <module>
    main()
File "C:\Users\misra\GithubProjects\AgriAI\web_app.py", line 351, in main
    prediction = model4.predict(single_pred)
File "c:\users\misra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py", line 119, in <lambda>
    out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\misra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 407, in predict
    Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
File "c:\users\misra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py", line 791, in transform
    X = self._validate_data(X, reset=False,
File "c:\users\misra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 436, in _validate_data
    self._check_n_features(X, reset=reset)
File "c:\users\misra\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 372, in _check_n_features
    raise RuntimeError(
```

I have looked at some solutions but they involve changing the scikit library version, is there a way to do this without changing the version?

Comment: Why did you dump `model` if you are not loading it afterwards? Also, later on in your script you are using `model4` instead of `model`. Can you explain?

Comment: I have loaded the model in another python script, I have not shown the code for it, I will add it also. The name's now `model4` because that script has different models which I also load in the script hence I named them as `model1, model2 and so on..`